# Stray '\' in program error

Tags: windows-xp, mingw, compilation, mingw32, biometrics

I'm using MinGW to compile NBIS, and everything goes ok up till the point when I have to run the 'make it' command. It compiles stuff for a little while, then it terminates with these errors:

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/c/NBIS/an2k/src/bin/histogen'
histogen.c:923:42: error: unterminated comment
gcc -O2 -w -ansi -DOPJ_STATIC -D_POSIX_SOURCE -DNO_FORK_AND_EXECL  -D__NBISLE__
  -D__MSYS__  -m32  -IC:/NBIS/an2k/include -IC:/NBIS/exports/include -c -o /c/NB
IS/an2k/src/bin/histogen/histogen.o histogen.c
histogen.c: In function 'help':
histogen.c:863:3: error: missing terminating " character
histogen.c:865:1: error: 'This' undeclared (first use in this function)
histogen.c:865:1: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for eac
h function it appears in
histogen.c:865:6: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'application'
histogen.c:865:6: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:867:1: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:869:1: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:871:1: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:873:1: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:875:1: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:877:1: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:877:1: error: missing terminating " character
histogen.c: In function 'usage':
histogen.c:899:3: error: missing terminating " character
histogen.c:901:3: error: 'Usage' undeclared (first use in this function)
histogen.c:901:3: error: invalid initializer
histogen.c:901:8: error: expected ',' or ';' before ':' token
histogen.c:901:8: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:903:3: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:905:6: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:907:6: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:909:6: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:911:6: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:911:6: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:913:4: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:915:4: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:915:4: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:917:4: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:919:4: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:921:4: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:921:4: error: stray '\' in program
histogen.c:923:42: error: unterminated comment
histogen.c:923:4: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
make[4]: *** [/c/NBIS/an2k/src/bin/histogen/histogen.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/c/NBIS/an2k/src/bin/histogen'
make[3]: *** [bins] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/c/NBIS/an2k/src/bin'
make[2]: *** [bins] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/NBIS/an2k/src'
make[1]: *** [bins] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/NBIS/an2k'
make: *** [it] Error 1
```

I've been stumbling along and managing to correct most errors I get, but I'm really stumped here. Here's links to the histogram files:

histogen.h - http://pastebin.com/Pae9Fty8
histogen.c - http://pastebin.com/v0W0GLXv

I would appreciate any help here, I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: what versions of mingw, gcc and nbis are you using to?